# myfirstapp is not working in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am getting problem when i try to run in-built myfirstapp project and get this error

```
[2013-01-16 00:37:34 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-01-16 00:37:34 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2013-01-16 00:37:34 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2013-01-16 00:37:35 - MyFirstApp] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-01-16 00:37:35 - MyFirstApp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

a window opens and android word keeps on shining but the the hello world file dont work

my computers configuration is `p4 2.4ghz,1.5ram` 
thanks in advance.

Comment: rephrase your question and highlight you problem with some code etc

Answer (score 0):

The Android emulator is notoriously slow, and your computer configuration isn't exactly speeding the process up.

You may have to wait a while for the emulator to launch. On my old P4, it could take between 20 minutes and an hour to launch, depending on the Android version.

You could try using one of the newer x86 intel images, as they require less... emulation. The older Android versions would emulate an entire ARM architecture, while the x86 images don't need to od that since they're built for x86 in the first place.

Other than that, you should launch the emulator once at the beginning, and just leave it running for the rest of your development time, as it will save you lots of time throughout the day.

Comment: thanks for your reply ....but is it take 20 min for a simple app(hello world)?and secondly how will i get to know that it is still processing?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether its hello world or skynet. The amount of time required for startup stays the same. What do you mean by `how will i get to know that it is still processing?`?

Comment: after processing for 5 min it showed me thisMyFirstApp] Installing MyFirstApp.apk...
[2013-01-16 02:47:11 - MyFirstApp] Failed to install MyFirstApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2013-01-16 02:47:11 - MyFirstApp] (null)
[2013-01-16 02:47:11 - MyFirstApp] Launch canceled!

Comment: try starting the emulator, wait for it to boot, unlock the screen and then launch your app from eclipse.

Comment: thanks for taking interest but emulator only showing android word that keeps on shining and how to unlock the screen? i dont have any option

Comment: When the android word goes away, you'll get a normal slide to unlock screen. It may take some time. Start the emulator, and take a break for an hour or two. Literally.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator startup can take some time, especially the first time around. Wait some more, until you see the Home screen in the emulator, unlock the screen. If you cannot see anything by that time, look for more specific exceptions in LogCat view.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem shows that your device is not ready to install the program and run them.means emulator is itself is not loaded yet.
so you have to wait for the complete loading of your emulator .

and see http://developer.android.com/ for more help

check whether u have all setting correct for your emulator.